# Laplacian solvers for inversion of large matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

I have a large matrix L of size 400,000 $\times $ 400,000 . I'm using this L matrix in the following way.

> Lin = L$^{-1}$
>
> C  = D -  B * Lin * B';

B,D are of appropriate sizes. L matrix is sparse and doesn't have any particular structure to it.

> From  C which is a dense matrix I'm computing the bottom $m$~$10$ eigenvectors to do further computations.

I'm working on a toy problem.On real-world datasets the size of L matrix will be much higher than this.

Can someone direct me to some literature or solvers which can solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Not an expert, but you probably don't want to invert large matrices for numerical reasons.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : yes , from what I read inversion is in the order of n^3 hence computing inversion for very large matrix is not a good idea.  But I'm not sure how to do it any other-way. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Actually I meant numerical *stability*, not running time, which, as you point out, is also an issue. Perhaps you can tell us what problem you actually want to solve. Also, ignoring numerical and other issues, you can invert matrices in $O(n^{2.373})$ (though the hidden constant is very, very large).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : I have to find the bottom 'm' , where m~10 eigen-vectors of the C matrix . I'm kind of working on low rank decomposition.

Comment: Perhaps you should update the question accordingly. The approach would be to find the bottom one using, say, the powering method (though perhaps other methods are more appropriate for gigantic matrices), and then find some way to iterate. Also let us know if $C$ happens to be sparse.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : ok, I  will update the question. C won't be sparse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood the problem, you want to compute a few eigenvectors associated with the smallest eigenvalues of $C:=D-BL^{-1}B^T$ (probably $C$ is symmetric and positive definite?). 
Since the matrices involved are sparse, you can use methods based on the Arnoldi method implemented, e.g., in [ARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK). A good feature of these methods is that you do not need to compute $C$ explicitly, but instead, you must be able to compute matrix-vector products.

An issue here is that since you want to compute the eigenvectors from the "bottom" part of the spectrum (does it mean smallest in magnitude if $C$ is not SPD?), you might need to use an analogue of the inverse power iteration, that is, you need to be able compute matvecs with the *inverse* of $C$, or, equivalently, *solve systems of the form* $Cx=f$ for given right-hand side vectors $f$.

The matrix $C$ has the Schur complement form and, as you already noticed, $L^{-1}$ is dense as it usually happens when attempting to invert sparse matrices so inverting it or trying to compute $C$ explicitly in some way is not a good option. If $C$ was well-conditioned, you can solve $Cx=f$ iteratively, e.g., by conjugate gradients or GMRES. These methods, similarly to the Arnoldi method in ARPACK, require only products with $C$ so you could, e.g., factorize $L$ and then the product with $C$ involves only multiplications with $B$, $B^T$, $D$, and a solution of a system with $L$:
$$
\begin{align}
g=Cu=(D-BL^{-1}B^T)u: && &v:=B^Tu,\\
                      && &\text{solve}\;Lw=v,\\
                      && &g:=Du+Bw.
\end{align}
$$
A possible drawback is that if $C$ was ill-conditioned, the convergence of CG could be slow.

If you are not affraid of factorizing or solving in any other way sparse indefinite systems, you can also consider the following alternative on how to obtain the solution of $Cx=f$. Consider the "augmented" system
$$\tag{$*$}
Mu:=\pmatrix{L&B^T\\B&-D}\pmatrix{y\\x}=\pmatrix{0\\-f}.
$$
You can verify that the $x$-component of the solution vector $u$ solves $Cx=f$.
This approach has a small disadvantage: depending on the properties of your matrices, $M$ is likely to be indefinite so some care when factorizing it is needed. Nevertheless, factors of $M$ are more likely to be sparse.

For more information on how to solve systems like ($*$), see, e.g., [this paper](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~benzi/Web_papers/MBenzi-p2.pdf). You can find a good overview of methods for solving such problems there including tons of references (although the paper was published already a few years ago).

Comment: Excellent answer; many thanks for the link to the paper too; I am working in Non-convex non-linear programming and this may be of great benefit. Thanks again.

Comment: @Autolatry You are welcome! I don't know what the matrices are exactly, but since it is related to graph Laplacians and solving systems with them, you might also have a look on [this paper](https://scholar.google.fr/citations?view_op=view_citation&user=L82mYv8AAAAJ&cstart=20&sortby=pubdate&citation_for_view=L82mYv8AAAAJ:ZeXyd9-uunAC). There is also a bunch of interesting papers citing it (see the list on Google Scholar) which might be useful.

Comment: Thanks very much but I'm afraid that link must be broken as I see a 404. Thanks.

Comment: @Autolatry Oops! Fixed.

Comment: That's great, many thanks!